# prevent browser timeout while running single line in php

Tags: php, sockets, timeout, flush

What is the most simple way to prevent browser timeout while running a single line in php ? for example running stream_socket_client on a host takes 5 minute for initiation of the connection (not reading and writing to it, just initiation) now when php gets to this line, browser usually time outs. I know that flushing something to the output can prevent such thing but how should I do that when a single command is running.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to httpd.conf, you could try set :

```
KeepAliveTimeout 500
```

Comment: hmm, definition : "The number of seconds Apache httpd will wait for a subsequent request before closing the connection" and how is that going to prevent the browser from timing out ? In my case browser is waiting for a response from server not vice versa

Comment: When there is no data to send to browser, apache still keeps communication line open, by sending some "empty" requests to browser. In other words - it keeps the connection alive. At least that's the idea. It wont hurt to try.

Comment: I checked that and nothing changes, browsers are timing out like before.